# Animal euthanasia in Halacha

Tags: halacha, animals, medicine, mussar-ethics, tzaar-baalei-chayyim

According to Halacha, is it prohibited or permissible to do animal euthanasia on sick or injured animals? Or would it be prohibited as a violation of Tzaar Balei Chayim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is permissible.

aish.com writes [here](https://aish.com/animals-euthanasia/)

> **We are permitted to put an animal to sleep to avoid its suffering.** The
> reason is because the Torah requires us to alleviate the pain of
> animals (based on the verse obligating us to help our fellow unload
> his overladen donkey (Exodus 23:5)). On the other hand, we are allowed
> to kill animals when we have a good reason – such as for their meat or
> if they are threatening us. Putting the two points together, we are
> allowed to euthanize an animal for the good justification of
> minimizing its pain. (See Rema E.H 5:14, Noda BiYehuda 2 Y.D. 10,
> Techumim X p. 258.)

ohr.edu [adds](https://ohr.edu/ask_db/ask_main.php/31/Q1/#:%7E:text=I%20asked%20Rabbi%20Chaim%20Pinchas,the%20ending%20of%20any%20life.)

> I asked Rabbi Chaim Pinchas Scheinberg, shlita, about the ruling in
> this case, and he told me that **it would be Halachically permissible to
> put an animal to sleep since it is a painless procedure**. However,
> there is a Kabbalistic tradition, he notes, that forbids the ending of
> any life.

See also [here](https://dinonline.org/2021/06/10/animal-euthanasia/).